# How do i fetch this json value standing_place for my database in php from the json object below

Tags: php, json

JSON:

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "result": {
    "total": [
      {
        "standing_place": "1",
        "standing_place_type": "Promotion - NBA (Play Offs)",
        "standing_team": "Toronto Raptors",
        "standing_P": "82",
        "standing_W": "59",
        "standing_WO": "0",
        "standing_L": "23",
        "standing_LO": "0",
        "standing_F": "9156",
        "standing_A": "8518",
        "standing_PCT": "0.720",
        "team_key": "51",
        "league_key": "787",
        "league_season": "2017/2018",
        "league_round": "Eastern Conference",
        "standing_updated": "2018-05-28 17:22:59"
      },
      {
        "standing_place": "3",
        "standing_place_type": "Promotion - NBA (Play Offs)",
        "standing_team": "Philadelphia 76ers",
        "standing_P": "82",
        "standing_W": "52",
        "standing_WO": "0",
        "standing_L": "30",
        "standing_LO": "0",
        "standing_F": "9004",
        "standing_A": "8635",
        "standing_PCT": "0.634",
        "team_key": "56",
        "league_key": "787",
        "league_season": "2017/2018",
        "league_round": "Eastern Conference",
        "standing_updated": "2018-05-28 17:23:00"
      }
  ]
}
```

PHP:

```
$APIkey='XXXXXXX';
$leagueId = 787;

$curl_options = array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://allsportsapi.com/api/basketball/?met=Leagues&APIkey=$APIkey&leagueId=$leagueId",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, $curl_options );
$result = curl_exec( $curl );

$result = (array) json_decode($result);

var_dump($result);

    $result =  json_decode($result);
    foreach($result as $mydata)
    {    foreach($result->result as $myresult)
        {
           foreach($myresult->total as $total)
        {
             $standing_place_type = $total->standing_place_type;
            }
        }
    }
```

This Json code is source from all sports APi I have work with some other Api but did not find this one fun to work with. I have try all the means know to me to solve this problem but all method prove abortive with empty result. please if you have work with the api before kindly help or if you have an idea how i can solve this problem please help

Answer (score 0):

What you have is basically there you just need to check that the `total` index exists prior to trying to use it:

```
foreach($result as $mydata) {
    if(!empty($mydata->total)){
        foreach($mydata->total as $total ){
            echo $total->standing_place_type . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/TS5Ae

Comment: this does not work for me.  total is  not empty when i var_dump result it displays the contents

Comment: @davidlemchidove Click the link result can be seen. Maybe you have different JSON structure?

Comment: this is how the structure looks like array(2) { ["success"]=> int(1) ["result"]=> array(395) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4856 (4) { ["league_key"]=> string(3) "734" ["league_name"]=> string(7) "1. Liga"

Comment: Please edit the question with your actual JSON, as a string, and I'll update answer.. or you can extrapolate answer to your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're more familiar with PHP than JSON notation, try to `print_r` the result of `json_decode` to see how the structure is being converted. It should be [like this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/567ff401d29389de478f7e26425e5d3e786fac80):

```php
$decodedJson = json_decode($json);
print_r($decodedJson);

// Result
stdClass Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
...
```

Can you see? It's an **object**, with a **result object**, with a **total object** with an **objects array**.

Now, knowing that you can access PHP objects public properties like this `$myObject->my_property` and arrays you can iterate with `foreach` like in your sample, you would navigate this structure in PHP like this:

```
// Check if the object contains the expected structure
if ($decodedJson && isset($decodedJson->result) && isset($decodedJson->result->total)) {
    // Iterate over Total Array
   foreach ($decodedJson->result->total as $total) {
       // Print values
       echo "Standing_Place: {$total->standing_place} / Standing_Place_Type: {$total->standing_place_type}." . PHP_EOL;
   } 
}
```

[Live sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/abc826472749ccdb13d7c5122e915d6d4944f611).

Obs: On the JSON you posted, there is a curly bracket missing in the end. You can validate the json [this site](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.co).